# Azure Function local git "RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400" if the repo is too large

Tags: git, azure-functions

Azure Function  shows `RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400` if the repo is too large

OS is Windows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2 actions are perform to fix the issue:

Action 1: Upgrade git to latest version https://git-scm.com/downloads

`git version 2.30.1.windows.1`

Action 2: Use `cmd` instead of `git bash` (Probably a bug...)

---

*Note: Stackoverflow allow answer own question https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer*

Comment: As outlined in [the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatdoescodehttppostBuffercodereallydo), `http.postBuffer` should not be used unless you know what it does, and if that does fix the problem, you have a larger issue that should be solved instead.

Comment: Thanks, after I check with the issue again. The issue is indeed solved by just the other 2 actions instead of setting `postBuffer`. I have removed the `postBuffer` action. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same error, it was likely due to a large amount of data being transferred. To resolve this issue, I had to increase the `http.postBuffer` size in the Git configuration.

For me, this command had done the trick

`git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

By increasing the http.postBuffer size, I was able to push changes.

Answer (score 0):

When you push your source code to the `Local Git` deployment to Azure, try to add the `-u` option on your push command.

```
git push -u origin master
```